# Datatypes in C#

Tags: c#, types, maxlength

I am in process to develope a C# application.
I have three fields here on a form. Not sure which would be appropriate datatype for them.
Some help will be appreciated.

```
a: length of this field is 30 and it should be a positive integer
b: length of this field is 15 and it should be a decimal allowed positive number
c: length of this field is 15 and it should be a decimal allowed unsigned number
```

Also what should be the datatype of following:

```
a*b
a*c
b*c
```

Comment: Datatypes in the database or are you talking about variables in the code?

Comment: Are you sure you can develop an application if you don't know the answer to this question?

Comment: You have a data field that is a 30-digit integer? What could you possibly be storing?

Comment: @John: Variables in code

Comment: @Jon: I am learning you see. And no question is lame when you are learning

Comment: @Sara: I certainly didn't say the question was lame or anything similar, nor did I downvote it. But learning and developing an application isn't the same. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and you can find the correct answer for each, it's really not that hard!

Comment: Sex isn't an issue. I didn't really answer, just nudged in the correct direction. As all homework questions should be I guess..

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

[image: c# built in Data Types and Their range/size of storage:]

You can checkout this Ultimate C# Guide for Beginners here: http://shoppingict.blogspot.com/2014/12/book-ultimate-c-guide-for-dummies.html

Comment: The blog that you have linked here seems to have been deleted.